# Switching Windows Boot Disk via GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 15.04

I have two drives in my laptop.
The first is dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu, and I've been using this one for over a year now (the Ubuntu version is now 15.04).
I have just (yesterday) installed a second HDD in my laptop, onto which I've copied the Windows partition.
The ideal scenario is to have Ubuntu on the 1st disk, and Windows on the 2nd.
I need to somehow (from Ubuntu) edit BCD and GRUB to tell them that Ubuntu is on the first disk, and Windows is on the second.
BTW, all files are backed up, so no worry about losing data.
Thanks